# Python: replacing all appearances of a class constructor in superclass from subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

This is probably a stupid question. But I encountered this need when writing a tool that needs to slightly modify the API from an existing package. The minimal example is as such

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("foo")        
    
class Qux(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print("qux")
        
class Baz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        
    def f(self):
        # ... a lot of code
        Foo()
        # ... a lot of code
        
    def g(self):
        # ... a lot of code
        Foo()
        # ... a lot of code

class Bar(Baz):
    Baz.Foo = Qux #（my rough idea but it doesn't work)
    

b = Bar()
b.f()
b.g()
# want to print qux all above
```

I want to achieve this without overloading all methods from `Baz` that used the `Foo` constructor to use `Qux` instead. Is there any way to do this without touching the code for the superclass?

Also, please kindly enlighten me if there's a name for such situation. I tried to search up solution on Stackoverflow but had no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need there is called "monkey patching" - an operation possible in dynamic languages such as Javascript, Python and Ruby, in which either a module level variable or an attribute of a class/instance is replaced by other at runtime.

It is popular with testing, as it allows one to replace functions and classes with mocks - but if used with wisdom, can be made to work in production code.

Its usage can range from simple to complicated, depending on how things are arranged there:

If you can change *all* occurrences and usages of `Bar` in the process to use Qux instead of Foo, and never look back - you are in luck for the simplest scenario, with no need for a `Baz` subclass, and no need to rollback the monkey-patching.

Let's suppose the usages of `Foo` in `Bar` code are just as shown in your example: the code assumes that there is a `Foo` name bound at module level (the module where `Bar` is declared), and just do `Foo()`, and not, in contrast, `module1.Foo()` - you just have to replace that name before instantiating any `Bar` objects.

If `Bar` is defined in `module2`, for example, you can write at the very beggining of your Python project (usually the `__init__.py` file at the project base, or, sometimes an `app.py` file for stuff that will run in containers)  you do:

```
import module2
from module3 import Qux

module2.Foo = Qux

# program follows as usual
(...)
from module2 import Bar
def myfun():
    x = Bar() # <- when this is run, `Bar` will actually "see" Qux insteaf of Foo
```

That was the simple thing. Now, there are intermediate scenarios, like `Foo` sometimes showing up as `Foo` and sometimes as `module1.Foo` in the source code, or `Foo` bein used in other places than in the `Bar` class - there are ways to adapt the idea above to handle that.

## using the `Baz` class approach

But if you really need a different `Baz` class, then we have to fine tune the change - and it won't be a proper "monkey patching" anymore. The original `Bar` class would run pointing to `Foo`, and `Baz` is a new, isolated class - as you ask for it. But it does not come down as simple inheritance -- it will require you to clone the `Bar` class into a new `Baz`. It can optionally be made to inherit from `Bar` if it is needed to pass `isinstance`  checks, though it will override all methods in the class with *clones* of those methods - and if there are uses of "super()" call in methods that also call `Foo()` it would require yet another level of hacking around.

I won't worry about fixing `super` calls right now - if you need these calls to work, please mention in the comments.

So the steps to be taken are:

- duplicate the `Bar` class by calling type with the new name, `Bar` as a base, and

  - iterating over all members of `Bar` and for each method, clone the method.
  - this clonning however should recreate the *function* objects, replacing the its `__globals__` attribute with a copy where `Foo` points to `Qux`.

Actually, "super()" calls will work straightforward - I found that out when trying to write some special code for it to work, it turns out it is the default behavior:  one will want to pass straight from the method in the cloned class to the method of the superclass of the original class (a method in Bar that uses `super()` will land directly in the superclass to Baz, skipping the original method in Baz, that is)

```
def replace_inner(base_cls, new_name, replacements):
    from types import FunctionType
    class New(base_cls):
        pass
    New.__name__ = new_name
    new_globals = None
    for name, obj in base_cls.__dict__.items():
        if not isinstance(obj, FunctionType):
            try:
                setattr(New, name, obj)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            continue
        if not new_globals:
            new_globals = copy(obj.__globals__)
            new_globals.update(replacements)
        new_func = FunctionType(obj.__code__, new_globals, obj.__name__, obj.__defaults__, obj.__closure__)
        setattr(New, name, new_func)
    return New
```

And this working in the interactive mode (Foo and Qux are defined as in your example)

```
In [52]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         print("A")
    ...:

In [53]: class B(A):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.f = Foo()
    ...:         super().__init__()
    ...:

In [54]: C = replace_inner(B, "C", {"Foo": Qux})

In [55]: c = C()
Qux
A

In [56]: c.f
Out[56]: <__main__.Qux at 0x7f0f399ac310>
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer, although I have to read two times to understand the solutions to different requirements. Luckily, my project belongs to the first case (this is after reading your answer and thinking again about my code) where I just need the `Bar` and can ignore the old `Baz`, and your suggestion works! I will come back later and try experiment with the second solution, but it does sounds a bit more elaborate with all that cloning of methods and modifying the `__globals__` attributes.

Comment: It will be nice if you can put up a minimal solution for the second case if you have time.